# Maven release:prepare cannot commit parent module

Tags: java, git, maven, github

I want to make a release with the maven release plugin in two steps:

```
1. mvn clean release:prepare
2. mvn release:perform
```

It worked fine the last two releases, but after changing my IDE from intellij to eclipse I am not able to perform a release this way with apache-maven 3.5.3 and eGit 4.9.2.

The general structure of my project is:

```
parent-dir
    -> pom.xml
    -> child1-dir
           -> pom.xml
    -> child2-dir
           -> pom.xml
```

child1 and child2 contain code and packaging to `jar`, the parent has packaging goal `pom`.
Configuration of maven-release-plugin in parent pom.xml:

```
      <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.1</version>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.shared</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-invoker</artifactId>
                    <version>2.2</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
```

The plugin updates all poms with correct version #, committs changes and pushes to the remote repository for both child modules. But for the parent module I get the following error at the end of the log:

```
[INFO] Reactor Summary:
[INFO] 
[INFO] test Parent 0.12-SNAPSHOT ........................ FAILURE [02:46 min]
[INFO] test Child1 ...................................... SUCCESS [  0.011 s]
[INFO] test Child2 0.12-SNAPSHOT ........................ SUCCESS [  0.205 s]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 02:48 min
[INFO] Finished at: 2018-09-08T12:56:06+02:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------    
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-release-plugin:2.5.1:prepare (default-cli) on project test-parent: Unable to commit files
[ERROR] Provider message:
[ERROR] The git-push command failed.
[ERROR] Command output:
[ERROR] git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
[ERROR] fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] Please make sure you have the correct access rights
[ERROR] and the repository exists.
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
```

I do not understand why I get this error message after succesfull commiting and pushing the children modules?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add your public key in Github.

For help please refer https://help.github.com/articles/adding-a-new-ssh-key-to-your-github-account/

Comment: Hi, I have almost added my ssh key to github. Otherwise commiting and pushing for the child modules would not be possible...

Comment: can you check `scm` configurations in `pom`. Make sure that user has write access to repository